# Disabled Text Input with onclick

Tags: javascript, text, input, onclick, disabled-input

I need a way of capturing onclick, for a text input that is disabled.
I would prefer not to use jQuery, but if there was no javascript alternative, would use it.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I have tried simply adding an onclick="" to a disabled text field, which did not work.
Is there any way to do it without jquery?
Thanks

Comment: `textInput.onclick = function() { alert('Like this?') }`

Comment: @Doorknob Where should I put this code? Does it need jQuery?

Comment: Just to clarify, jQuery is 101% JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about delegation events to parent elements like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RXqAm/768/)?

```
<span style="position:relative;" onClick="event.target.value='clicked';">
  <input type="text" disabled "/>
</span>
```

*If my answer is acceptable please comment it and I'll make an explanation.*

Answer (score 0):

You are probably lookinf for this:-

```
$("div").click(function (evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
});
```

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RXqAm/766/)**

Comment: OP said they want to do it without jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

This is the modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXqAm/767/) proposed by Rahul Tripathi using pure javascript.

This is the function that made it works:

```
document.getElementById("textInput").onclick = function() {
    alert("Input clicked");
}
```