# javascript disabled button ondblclick with this

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, this

I have a button that has a doubleclick event, that I want to run, regardless of whether the button is enabled or disabled. I posted a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816961/disabled-text-input-with-onclick), but now I need to run a function from the disabled button that uses the`this` paramater, and if I use the `<span>` workaround, as described in the other question, it gives me the info about the `<span>` element, not the `<button>` element.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NRKLG/5/)

How can I get round this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have two elements with same ids. Your markup should look like that:

```
<button name='name_of_button' id='id_of_button1' ondblclick="runFunction( this );">Enabled Button</button>
<br>
<button name='name_of_button' id='id_of_button2' ondblclick="runFunction( this );" disabled>Disabled Button</button>
```

Second, it is not a good idea to use inline javascript. However, your problem could be solved like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button name='name_of_button'>Enabled Button</button>
    <div class="over"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button name='name_of_button' disabled="disabled">Disabled Button</button>
    <div class="over"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var dblClicked = function() {
        console.log(this.parentNode.childNodes[1].removeAttribute("disabled"));
    }
    var overlays = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper .over");
    for(var i=0; i<overlays.length; i++) {
        var over = overlays[i];        
        over.addEventListener("dblclick", dblClicked);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NRKLG/12/

If the element is disabled it can't trigger events. This means that you can't listen for dblclick even if you add the listener to the parent element. So, you should put an overlay transparent div over the button.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. My goal is to allow the disabled button to be used whilst disabled, not to re-enable it.

Comment: As far as I know if the element is disabled you can't listen for events from it. So, you should wrap it in a div and attach the dblclick event on it.

Comment: I would do this, but I need the `this` part to work with the burron