# How can events be enabled for a disabled input?

Tags: css, input, disabled-input

[These solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816961/disabled-text-input-with-onclick) (copied below) don't work because the `value` of the input is preset and needs to scroll horizontall..and the absolutely positioned div covers the input and prevents it from scrolling..

```
<span style="position:relative;">
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <div id="textInput" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; cursor: pointer;" ></div>
</span>
document.getElementById("textInput").onclick = function() {
    alert("Input clicked");
}
```

Any suggestions to enable events, while keeping the input scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it `readonly` rather than `disabled`.

Comment: any suggestions for keeping the cursor from appearing? would this be css?

Comment: Yup, `cursor: none` should do it.

Comment: Ah, this is actually the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text .. thanks for the tip though, the readonly functionality is really perfect