# How can I make only the focused input available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to always make only one input enable. To achieve that, I can disable inputs by adding `disabled` attribute and remove that attribute on clicking by jQuery. Like this:

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
})
```

```css
input, div{
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="/mypath">
  <input type="text" disabled ><br>
  <input type="text" disabled ><br>
  <input type="text" disabled >
</form>
```

Unfortunately nothing happens on click. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabled Text Input with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816961/disabled-text-input-with-onclick)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled elements don't execute mouse events. So you should select them indirectly. One way is adding an element in front of the disabled input to simulate clicking on that element. This is the only way for complete cross browser compatibility.

Noted that you should hide/show that element on `click`:

```
$(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
```

and on `blur`:

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true).next("div").show();
```

Full Version Of The Code:

```js
$('form#myform > div').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
})

$('form#myform > input').on('blur', function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true).next("div").show();
})
```

```css
input, div{
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div{
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -22px; /* I've used 22 instead of 20 because of input border */
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="/mypath">
  <input type="text" disabled >
  <div></div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" disabled >
  <div></div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" disabled >
  <div></div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `disabled`, you can use `readonly` because `disabled` elements don't have events (you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/1925666)).

```js
$('input').on('click', function() {
  $('input').prop('readonly', true);
  $(this).prop('readonly', false);
})
```

```css
input,
div {
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="/mypath">
  <input type="text" readonly><br>
  <input type="text" readonly><br>
  <input type="text" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: No I want `disabled` attribute.